# Is there way to use Obsidian Sync from Neovim?

Tags: neovim

Now, when I make changes in my [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) notes using Neovim I need to keep Obsidian app opened, to make [Obsidian sync](https://obsidian.md/sync) work.

Is there a way to make it sync without keeping app opened?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify: What is Obsidian? How does it sync?